# How to get the menu item ID by page ID/slug in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have added a page "shop" to the custom menu, then I want to get the "shop" menu item ID by the page ID or slug, is it possible to do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no menu id, you can simply use the page id or slug.